# simple_form label to be column value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using simple_form in rails and have a situation where I want the label to be the value from another field. In this case that field is not to be changed and so I don't want to be on the form.

To explain a bit better I have two lines that look like

```
<%= f.input :name, :label => false, :disabled => true, :input_html => { :class => 'input-small' } %>
<%= f.input :status, :collection => ["Not started", "Passed", "Failed"], :include_blank => false, :label => false %>
```

What I'd like to do is have the first element to be the label of the second element. Now I could do this by having them inline, but I'd like them to be lined up with the other elements so that the labels and inputs are lined up.

so doing something like

```
<%= f.input :status, :collection => ["Not started", "Passed", "Failed"], :include_blank => false, :label => f.name %>
```

or

```
<%= f.input :status, :collection => ["Not started", "Passed", "Failed"], :include_blank => false, :label => {f.input :name, :label => false, :disabled => true} %>
```

Any thoughts on how to get around this?

Michael

Comment: could rephrase your question?

Comment: @MichealMoulsdale Look like disable functionality to me

Comment: Disable functionality gets me part of the way there, but doesn't really have the styling I'd like. I'd want the label to be lined up with all the other labels and to be a disabled field value of a different variable.

Comment: what i'd ideally like to do is either '<%= f.input :status, :label => f.name %>' or '<%= f.input :status, :label => {f.input :name, :label => false, :disabled => true} %>'

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution to this? I need to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did indeed go for the inline option, which isn't ideal but did the job. However I had to do the following.

The main form set as a norm form
The block below that set as form-horizontal

then the subform partial defined as a none simple_form

```
<div class="control-group form-inline">
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :name, :disabled => 'true', :size => 10 %>
    <%= f.select(:status, [["Not started","Not started"], ["Passed", "Passed"], ["Failed", "Failed"]]) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

If it was set as a simpleform the inline would not work as required. Again not perfect, and certainly not elegant, but worked

Answer (score 1):

'f.object' gets the object associated to that form and then you can get to the fields:

```
<%= f.select(:status, [["Not started","Not started"], ["Passed", "Passed"], ["Failed", "Failed"]]), :label => f.object.name %>
```